# Getting Error When trying to stop weblogic Managed server using nmKill() command

Tags: weblogic, middleware, weblogic12c, weblogic11g, oracle-fusion-middleware

I have a requirement to Restart Managed servers via NodeManager but without AdminServer.

Using WLST I could start Managedserver using NM. (nmConnect, nmStart).

But for Stopping a Managedserver without Admin. I see the option nmKill. But I don't want to kill the process rather want to do a proper shutdown.

**1. is it possible to connect to managed server using WLST when Admin is not Available?**

If not above is a possible way to shutdown, resume a managed server without Adminserver.

Weblogic 12 in dev mode is the version I have installed.

**2. Also, When I tried to stop my server using nmKill(), I am getting below error:**

```
/> nmKill('ms_node1')
Killing server ms_node1 ...
Traceback (innermost last):
File "<console>", line 1, in ?
File "<iostream>", line 150, in nmKill
File "<iostream>", line 553, in raiseWLSTException
```

WLSTException: Error occurred while performing nmKill : Error killing server ms_node1 : Received error message from Node Manager Server: [Server kill command for WebLogic server 'ms_node1' failed due to: [Waited for the process to finish for 20,000 millis, without success. This is a known limitation with the java.lang.Process.destroy call when the managed process has child or sub process such as a start script calling java. Users should perform the preferred method of connecting to the AdminServer to issue a shutdown request to stop a server. Only when that fails should nmKill be used. When there are no other options to stop the process, the OS level process kill should be used.]. Please check Node Manager log and/or server 'ms_node1' log for detailed information.]. Please check Node Manager log for details.
Use dumpStack() to view the full stacktrace :

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can stop if from the command line using stopWebLogicManagedServer.cmd, if you only need to kill the cluster.

Comment: I agree sir but my requirement is to stop/start Admin/managed servers using nodemanager from wlst.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but you need to have started it with NodeManager for this to actually work, from oracle's documentation :

> nmKill
>
> Kills the specified server instance that was started with
>   Node Manager. If you attempt to kill a server
>   instance that was not started using Node Manager, the command displays
>   an error. In the event of an error, the command returns a
>   WLSTException.

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLSTC/reference.htm#WLSTC492